# How to draw right Triangles shape in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]

How to create shape in android using xml?

Comment: dont do that in xml, its a waste of time, instead draw it using `Canvas` API

Answer (score 6):

**Updated, Now a Right angle triangle**
This will work for sure
1[image]

1. This code will make a left sided triangle like in the photo above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="52"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-45%"
            android:pivotY="90%" >

            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >

                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2 [image]

2. This code will make a Right sided triangle like in the photo above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-50"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="140%"
            android:pivotY="90%" >

            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >

                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This don't work. It is an equilateral triangle. And I want an rigth.

Comment: could you please explain the login behind, solution is perfect but I don't know we made it.

Comment: @NishchayZacariah As Triangle is not a default shape, we rotate a Rectangle first in shape of a Rhombus or a Diamond using the `fromDegrees` and `toDegrees`, then, we shift the shape out of the view using `pivotX` and `pivotY` to make the required shape area visible, in this case, a triangle. So, it's always a Rectangle but visibly, Triangle because other part is out of view bounds and not visible. To rotate a rectangle Right side or left side in a diamond/Kite shape, we use `fromDegrees` and `toDegrees` and then, we move it accordingly.

Comment: Understood Lalit, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

Also check my another answer [How to create vector drawable in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797343/12636730)

[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="113dp"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    android:viewportHeight="113">
  <path
      android:pathData="M2.423,111.534L105.599,110.724L1.032,3.022L2.423,111.534Z"
      android:strokeWidth="2"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="119dp"
    android:height="126dp"
    android:viewportWidth="119"
    android:viewportHeight="126">
  <path
      android:strokeWidth="1"
      android:pathData="M117.632,124.928L1.686,125.144L118.003,2.092L117.632,124.928Z"
      android:fillColor="#ffffff"
      android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this to make lines.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>
```

You got line, drawing triangle is no big deal now.

Comment: Although this answer does draw a line, there is no indication how to rotate the lines and line them up.