# drawing a triangle using Vector path and XML in android

Tags: android, xml, svg, vector, drawable

I have found how to draw a triangle, but I need to rotate it now and I can't seem to make it..

My goal is to reach this:

[image]

So far I have found this code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <group android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="@color/some_color"
            android:pathData="m 50,0 l 50,50 -100,0 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

but it appears like this :

[image]

Comment: so why dont you use some vector graphics tool like [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)? yes, its free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to add these attributes in `group` :

```
android:pivotX="50"
android:pivotY="50"
android:rotation="45"
```

Comment: it works, but for some reason when I use it on an ImageView, it has a padding. Where is that padding coming from?

Comment: My guess is that you set the `viewport` to be 100, but by rotating the triangle of 45° you're not filling this area anymore, hence the padding.

Comment: so how can I overcome it?

Comment: Maybe if you draw the triangle already rotated it should be fine. Try this path `M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 z` and without any rotation.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered,
But follow this way to make your own custom vector drawable.

To make your own custom vector drawable convert your image to svg or psd format and upload your image to android studio as below.

Step 1: Right click on drawable folder, go to new and then select vector asset like this.

[image]

Step 2: Now check the Local File (SVG, PSD) radio button and upload your SVG or PSD file.
[image]
[image]

What else! Finally you will get your vector drawable file.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <group android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="@color/some_color"
            android:pathData="M 0,0 L50,0 50,50 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```